# How do I group downloaded files in the same subdirectory on a per item basis in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to download files from a website using `scrapy` and have successfully gotten things to work. Currently all of the files save to the same folder as expected. Is it possible to save the files to different subdirectories according to the `scrapy` item they belong to/came from?

This is what my current pipeline implementation looks like (subclasses `FilesPipeline`):

```
import hashlib
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from scrapy.utils.python import to_bytes

class XeroPipeline(FilesPipeline):

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        original_path = super(XeroPipeline, self).file_path(request, response=None, info=None)
        root = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(request.url)).hexdigest()
        if "objectUID" in request.url:
            return root + '/' + original_path + '.jpeg'
        else:
            return root + '/' + original_path + '.pdf'
```

but this just saves each file in a separate folder. I can’t seem to get a reference to the `scrapy` item so I can’t differentiate where each request is coming from. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: _Is it possible to save the files to different subdirectories according to the item they belong to/came from?_ Yes, most likely. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: How do I do so? @AMC I can’t seem to get the item so I can’t differentiate where each request is coming from

Comment: _I can’t seem to get the item so I can’t differentiate where each request is coming from_ What item? Remember that we know nothing about your program, eh.

Comment: This question specifically references scrapy, a web crawler framework in Python.. So the item is a Scrapy item https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html... @AMC

Comment: Can you give us an example as how it saves the files right now in your file system? And possibly what's exactly the desired result instead.

Comment: You could try overriding `process_item` to, after calling the parent implementation, store whatever item data you need into the `info` object (`info.item_data = …`).